# where to load grails message when throwing exception in a service

Tags: grails

Where should the separation of the UI message elements be if a grails service throws an exception?  Should the message get loaded by the service and passed to the controller via the exception, or should the controller load the message based on the type of exception thrown?  This assumes the message will have some parameter values that need to be filled in.

Here is an exception:

```
class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
    String message
}
```

Loading the message source from the controller after catching the exception:

```
class MyService {
    void doSomething() {
        ...
        if (somethingBad) {
            String value = 'Mary Smith'
            throw new CustomException(value)
        }
        ...
    }
 }
 class MyController {
    def myService

    void processRequest() {
        try {
            myService.doSomething()
        }
        catch (CustomException e) {
            flash.error = g.message(code:'user.input.error', args:'[${e.value}]')
            render view:'some_gsp'
        }
        ...
    }
 }
```

Loading error from message source in the service where the controller pulls the message string the from the exception:

```
class MyService {
    def messageSource
    void doSomething() {
        ...
        if (somethingBad) {
            String value = 'Mary Smith'
            throw new CustomException(messageSource.getMessage('thread.inactive.user', [value]))
        }
        ...
    }
}
class MyController {
    def myService

    void processRequest() {
        try {
            myService.doSomething()
        }
        catch (CustomException e) {
            flash.error = e.message
            render view:'some_gsp'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. It's more commonly done in the controller since that is UI based responsibility. Also, using exceptions like that in services to control transactions commit/rollback is going to be a performance hit (do you really need it to fill out the entire stack every time you throw that exception or any other exception? Remember Grails has a HUGE stack to fill in every single time...). Exceptions should be EXCEPTIONAL not expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly speaking, **neither** of those two places do you need the translations. :)

**Separation Of Concern**
Controller should only worry about HTTP methods and its delegation.
Services should take care of transactions and underlying business logic.

**Declarative Error Handling**
For `2.0.*` and above, Grails provides you a sweet spot for handling errors. Guess what? [Declarative Error Handling](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToResponseCodes)

All exception related code moves to a separate controller (in house) where they are handled properly, keeping your business controllers and services clean and abstracted from boiler plate codes.

For Grails `2.3.*`, an [added feature was to handle exception](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#controllerExceptionHandling) in the controller itself but most of the boiler plate (try catch stuff) is abstracted from the controller implementation.

**Conclusion**
If you are using `v2.0.*` and above then your controllers would look something like:

```
class MyController {
    def myService

    def processRequest() {
        myService.doSomething()
        ...
    }
 }

//URL Mapping
static mappings = {
   "500"(controller: "errors", action: "customException",
         exception: CustomException)
}

//Error Controller
class ErrorsController {
    def customException() {
        def exception = request.exception
        // perform desired processing to handle the exception
    }
}
```

You can move the logic of error handling to a separate plugin if required in order to handle variety of errors/exception and unhappy paths. It becomes elegant to separate this concern.

If you are using `v2.3.*` then your controller would look something like:

```
class MyController {
    def myService

    def processRequest() {
        myService.doSomething()
        ...
    }

    def handleCustomException(CustomException e) {
        //Move this translation to src/groovy/utility if feasible
        flash.error = g.message(code:'user.input.error', args:'[${e.value}]')
        render view:'some_gsp'
    }
 }
```

In this case no handling required from services as well, you just need to throe that exception.

I suppose you would get more input from various sources as well if you look around and are interested to use this pattern.